# You Tube Videos Won't Play in Chrome at a Custom Speed, but Play in IE With Lots of Audio Problems

Tags: audio, youtube

I recently reinstalled Windows 8.1 on my laptop and noticed that Chrome isn't playing YouTube Videos at any custom speed (a speed other than 1x).  While watching the video, if I update the speed, the video stops, and the loading icon is displayed indefinitely.  I can play them in IE, but the audio is extremely bad.  Also my Windows Audio Device Graph Isolation process is using about 5-7% CPU (on an 8 core system, this nearly half of a single core).

Comment: How exactly do you figure that 5-7% CPU usage is half of a single core?  CPU usage isn't broken down like that.....

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm assuming that it is single threaded.  Besides that %100/8 core = 12.5%/core  so 5-7 is roughly half.

Comment: I will again repeat that, CPU system usage, isn't calculated like that.

Comment: @Ramhound the point of me mentioning the cores was just to say that that it's more CPU intensive than a machine with only one core at the same CPU percentage.  If my understanding of CPU% is wrong, feel free to teach me rather than chastising me without teaching.

Answer (score 1):

Going to the Sound menu, selecting the default playback device, properties, advanced, the default format was 24bit 192000 hz, which was the highest possible value.  Clicking Restore Defaults fixed my problem, by setting it down to DVD level.