# Changing YouTube playback speed doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, youtube

Whenever I use YouTube on Google Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.120 m), I'm unable to change the playback speed of the video. Changing the playback speed of the video causes the video to crash and the only way to fix it is to refresh the page.

Here's a representation of what that looks like, I have enabled statistics in case that matters.

[image]

On the other hand it seems to work fine on Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox and Safari.

As you know the YouTube player uses HTML5 so I don't suspect that the problem is with the Flash Player. Maybe the NVidia Card I am using might be creating issues (GeForce 755M SLI + 340.52).

I am using Windows 8.1 and the problem exists while using Chrome in Desktop mode as well as Metro UI mode. I tried re installing NVidia Drivers, Chrome, Restoring factory settings on Chrome etc.

I submitted an issue to YouTube as well but they haven't replied back to me. Other users seem to be having this problem as well, and it has been discussed on [Google's Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/JLyhEmnpKIo).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You Tube Videos Won't Play in Chrome at a Custom Speed, but Play in IE With Lots of Audio Problems](http://superuser.com/questions/812975/you-tube-videos-wont-play-in-chrome-at-a-custom-speed-but-play-in-ie-with-lots). There is an unaccepted answer to that question you might like to try.

Comment: @DavidPostill That was some amazing stuff. It worked. Thanks! But I'll still leave the question open in order to attract an explanation regarding why IE and other browsers were okay with this whereas Chrome wasn't.